# Promise not expecting a resolve or a reject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, jasmine2.0

To test one of my AngularJs Service I was writing to Unit tests.

Here is a sample code I've came up with :

```
it('', function(done) {
    aDocument.retrieveServiceFile(extractedFileFeature)
        .then(function() {
            expect(true).toBeFalsy();
        }, function() {
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        });
    $rootScope.$digest();
    done();
}
```

I just want to check if the defer has been resolved or reject. 
I don't find it really satisfying as the expect isn't really explicit.

Is there a better way than this to check whether the deferred has been rejected or resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some advice, I went for the following solution which is pretty easy to read and understand !

```
promise.then(function() {
    shouldHaveBeenHere = false;
}, function() {
    shouldHaveBeenHere = true;
}).finally(function() {
    expect(shouldHaveBeenHere).toBeTruthy();
});
```